# ¿Cómo obtener la fecha guardada en MySQL desde programa en Java?

Tags: java, mysql, date, jdatechooser

El programa que se está desarrollando permite buscar reservaciones de acuerdo a la fecha de llegada, esta fecha se selecciona en un JDateChooser, del cual se obtiene la fecha de la siguiente manera para ser usada en la consulta:

```
int dia = calFecha.getCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int mes=calFecha.getCalendar().get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
int year =calFecha.getCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR);
fecha = year+"/"+mes+"/"+dia;
```

La consulta que se realiza es la siguiente:

```
consulta="select noReservacion, titularReserva, telefono, email,fechaLlegada,fechaSalida, costo, cantidadAdultos, cantidadNinos,cantidadHabitaciones,estado from Reservacion where fechaLlegada='"+fecha+"'";
```

La consulta funciona de manera correcta, el problema es cuando el resultado de dicha consulta lo muestra en un JTable, es decir, si en la base de datos tengo el campo fechaLlegada='2019-06-08' en la celda correspondiente del JTable fechaLlegada tiene el valor de '2019-06-07' es decir lo pone como un día antes. El mismo problema ocurre con la fecha de salida.
La forma en la que se llena la tabla es la siguiente(donde tm es el DefaultTableModel del JTable):

```
while(rs.next())
{
    Object[] fila = new Object[11];
    //llenar la fila con el resultado de la consulta
    for(int i =0;i<fila.length;i++)
    {
        fila[i] = rs.getObject(i+1);
    }
    tm.addRow(fila);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sé a qué se deba pero la forma en que logré que se obtenga tal y como está en la base de datos es cambiando `rs.getObject()` por `rs.getString()`, solo así ha logrado funcionar.